# Google Protobufs in Java: How do you get a Message.Builder from a FieldDescriptor?

Tags: java, buffer, protocols, protocol-buffers

I have a FieldDescriptor for a message field defined in my protocol buffer.  I want to start constructing a value for that field, but I'm stuck trying to get a Message.Builder for that FieldDescriptor.  The code I'm writing is extremely generic - It's designed to serialize between MongoDB and Protocol Buffers - so I can't use any specialized logic for the Objects I happen to be using today.

The FieldDescriptor's JavaType is MESSAGE.  It's MessageType is a bit better, as it contains the message's Type, but the Type is in protocol buffer namespace, so I still can't use reflection to get a Message for it (at least not cleanly).

I'm not sure what else to do.  Anyone know how to construct a Message.Builder from a FieldDescriptor?

Comment: I did the same task for converting protobuf messages to sql and sql to proto. 
FieldDescriptor contains getMessageType() method, it returns Descriptors.Descriptor which contains a list of Fields. Constructing Message.Builder from Descriptor is a little bit tricky, I'll show the solution when came to office

Comment: Sounds as though ancalled will provide you with the answer; but you can use DynamicMessage (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/DynamicMessage) and in particular DynamicMessage.newBuilder() and DynamicMessage.parseFrom() to process protocol buffers messages dynamically. One example is here https://gist.github.com/nandub/950285

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an instance of the containing type's builder, you can get the builder for the field with:

```
containingBuilder.getFieldBuilder(fieldDescriptor)
```

or you can get a new builder for a message of the field's type (but not specifically the field of the existing instance):

```
containingBuilder.newBuilderForField(fieldDescriptor)
```

If you don't have an instance of the containing type at all, but you know the containing class, you can do:

```
ContainingType.getDefaultInstanceForType()
              .getField(fieldDescriptor)
              .newBuilderForType()
```

If you don't even know the containing class (perhaps it isn't even in your jar), and all you have is a descriptor, then you can use `DynamicMessage`:

```
DynamicMessage.newBuilder(fieldDescriptor)
```

However, note that `DynamicMessage` only emulates the reflection interface of the real class; it is not actually an instance of the real class (as would be generated by `protoc`). Also, it is a lot slower than the real class.